How are these old (1900s era) US screw-in fuse boxes internally connected?



(ignore the arrows)
The above pictures show the electrical panels in a house that was built in Illinois in 1909. I do not know for sure how original this wiring is, but I would guess that some upgrades were made at some point since one of the panels had an asbestos cover in it (now professionally removed along with the rest of the asbestos) and the others are metal.
There are two issues in these panels: the fuses' current ratings are too high for the wire guage and some screws are double tapped. I want to fix these problems myself, but I am not confident with doing so because it is not clear to me how these panels are internally connected and I don't want to be screwing or unscrewing wires to make that pigtail without knowing what is and is not live. At minimum, I need a reliable neutral to check for voltage compared to (and I will use a NCV as an extra layer of protection). I will also replace the screw-in fuses with screw-in circuit breakers of an appropriate size.
Take, for example, the first picture. Based solely on appearance, I would guess that the two black wires in the middle are two phases of 120V and the silver area on the bottom is a neutral bus (where there is no grounding because the system is old). To test this hypothesis, I probed across the two black wires in the center with a multimeter in AC voltage mode and got approximately 240V as expected, but then from the left black wire to what I thought was the neutral bus gives me 0V and then 240V from the other black wire to what I thought was the neutral bus. So, my guess was wrong, but I can't think of any sensible way for this to be wired that is compatible with what I saw. Frankly, it makes me suspect that I was just getting a bad connection or my multimeter is failing.
Also, one of the receptacles outside near the garage is 120V split phase (about 60V measured from live or neutral holes to ground hole, and about 120V between live hole and neutral hole). Other outlets read live, neutral, and ground holes as expected. Not all outlets are grounded and I am suspicious of the ones that are since I don't see any grounding system, but there's some modern-looking romex in some places and I don't see any modern-looking romex terminating in any of these panels that I know of so I don't know where that ground eventually goes (Later, I'll follow the romex in the basement and see where it goes).
I tried to find information about how these panels are supposed to be connected with search terms like "edison screw fuse box", but I could not find anything that explains this. Is my best bet to buy insulated tools, gloves, etc. and probe these circuits while they're live? That seems unnecessarily dangerous.
The specific questions:

What is this style of wiring called, so I can go look up information about it?
What is the basic plan for how these panels are supposed to be connected? I am not at all certain that these panels are in reality connected how they are supposed to be, even for 1909 standards because there's a lot of sketchy DIY work in this house.

Also, this will be replaced eventually with a modern system, but until that happens I want to understand how these work.

I would think the hot wires(from the meter/main fuse) would be inside the plastic/black and the black wires you see will be fused(protected)/switched hots.  Should be trained/know what you are doing before working with live power.

Based merely on wire size the black and red at the top of the first picture are presumably the supply, with the remaining screws being fused circuits. The supply should connect to the center contact of the screw-in fuses, the output to the outer shell. I would not  around with changing to screw-in breakers. I'd replace these historical artifacts with modern breaker panels ASAP. There are way too many live exposed parts for my taste in these things.

The pictures are not large enough to zoom in and attempt to discern details of the wiring, which might not be all that visible anyway. Seems to be a mixture of mostly plastic-covered newer wire and some cloth-covered older wire, but can't tell if the cloth is in metal armor or if the plastic has chopped off (or creatively connected not to code) ground wires.

Your voltage readings are concerning, almost like a bad/loss neutral somewhere.

60V is definitely not a reading you should ever see in a working US/North America AC circuit. It most likely indicates a bad connection somewhere.

Can you post a clear photo of the electric meter on this house of yours? It'd help us rule out a couple of odd possibilities, especially considering what I'm seeing in the middle picture

Many locales allow "grandfathering" very minor changes in old wiring that does not meet current codes. However, some of those photos lead me to believe that the system is so old as not to have any ground wires.
In that case, I'd rip out all the old wiring and install modern circuit breakers with GFCI, and modern wiring meeting current code. Yes, that is an expense, and means opening walls, but it would allow for installation of current conveniences at the same time, such as Ethernet, alarm wiring, etc.
